# Term for rhetorical refrain

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, rhetoric, rhetorical-devices

In the widely followed hearing on Judge Kavanaugh's confirmation to the United States Supreme Court, Senator Kamala Harris said to Kavanaugh's accuser of sexual assault;

> You have called for an independent investigation
>
> Judge Kavanaugh has not.
>
> You have called for independent witnesses
>
> Judge Kavanaugh has not.
>
> You have submitted yourself to a polygraph test
>
> Judge Kavanaugh has not.

Is there a term for this rhetorical technique, where a sort of refrain punctuates several statements?

I searched Google but couldn't find a word more suited than "refrain," though I suspect there is a more appropriate term out there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Senator Harris is using "repetition", a common rhetorical device.

> [**Repetition**](https://literarydevices.net/repetition/) is a literary device that repeats the same words or phrases a few times to make an idea clearer and more memorable. There are several types of repetition commonly used in both prose and poetry.
>
> [**Repetition**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=repetition+as+a+literary+device&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=repetition+as+a+literary+device&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.13223j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is a literary device that repeats the same words or phrases a few times to make an idea clearer and more memorable. ... As a rhetorical device, it could be a word, a phrase, or a full sentence, or a poetical line repeated to emphasize its significance in the entire text.

There are quite a few [**types of repetition**](https://literarydevices.net/repetition/) and Harris uses an **epimone**.

> - [**Epimone**](https://www.thoughtco.com/epimone-rhetoric-term-1690662) (pronounced eh-PIM-o-nee) is a rhetorical term for the frequent repetition of a phrase or question; dwelling on a point. Also known as perseverantia, leitmotif, and refrain.

A very good example of an epimone can be seen in Shakespeare's Julius Caesar. Who doesn't remember...

> Here, under leave of Brutus and the rest
> For Brutus is an **honourable man**;
> So are they all, all **honourable men**--
> Come I to speak in Caesar's funeral.
> He was my friend, faithful and just to me;
> But Brutus says he was **ambitious**;
> And Brutus is an **honourable man**.
> He hath brought many captives home to Rome
> Whose ransoms did the general coffers fill;
> Did this in Caesar seem **ambitious**?
> When that the poor have cried, Caesar hath wept:
> **Ambition** should be made of sterner stuff:
> Yet Brutus says he was **ambitious**;
> And Brutus is an **honourable man**.
> You all did see that on the Lupercal
> I thrice presented him a kingly crown,
> Which he did thrice refuse. Was this **ambition**?
> Yet Brutus says he was **ambitious**;
> And, sure, he is an **honourable man**. . . .

-- (Mark Antony in William Shakespeare's Julius Caesar, Act 3, scene 2)

Comment: Excellent. I studied *Julius Caesar* for my "O Level" GCE English Literature about 60 years ago, and Anthony's funeral speech remains as powerful today as it did then.